# How can we add android nugets in Xamarin.forms and not only in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to install the below NuGet in a Xamarin Forms Project(and not on Xamarin.Android project)

- Xamarin.Android.Support.core.Utiles
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable

I want to access the `MediaProjectionManager` in my Xamarin project class without platform-specific conditions. Please help me with this.

Right now whenever I am trying to install the android related NuGet packages in Xamarin Forms project I am getting the below error.

```
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 28.0.0.3 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 28.0.0.3 supports:
  - monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0)
  - monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
  - monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1)
  - monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)
  - monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)
  - monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)    

Error Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for .
```

If I write the below code in the cs file in the Xamarin project and if I try to access the below object from the MainActivity.cs file in the Xamarin.Android project, am getting below error.

The MediaProjection object is not available in XamarinFile. It is not able to access any android related function or object.

```
#if __ANDROID__
        public MediaProjection MediaProjection { get; set; }
#endif

XamarinFile.Instance.MediaProjection = manager.GetMediaProjection((int)resultCode, data);
```

Comment: That is an Android specific library.  You can't install it in the common Forms project.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the comment. I edited my question. I am not able to access any android related object written in Xamarin.Forms from MainActivity.cs file in Xamarin.Android project

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do but I'm almost positive you're going about it the wrong way.  I believe that I already told you in a prior question that using #if in a .NET Standard project is not going to work.  I would suggest you write a new question that explains what you're trying to accomplish and ask for the **proper** way to achieve it.

Comment: The most common way to implement platform dependent code is via DI, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction That's why you are not supposed to add any iOS or Android specific packages to a .NET Standard project.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the comment. According to this We can use #if for platform specific question. I am trying to implement platform specific code in Xamarin.form file. Which is communicate with Xamarin.Android file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation

Comment: "Conditional compilation works best with Shared Asset Projects".  You are not using a SAP, you are using a .NET Standard Library.

Comment: in this case,you could write the content what you want in the android project,then use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call it in forms project

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install an Android-specific library into a Xamarin .NET Standard/PCL project which is not compatible. The error itself clearly tells that. If you want to have any platform-specific functionality for your Xamarin Forms application, then you can try to create a custom view for it and write a custom renderer in the native projects. In the corresponding native project, install the desired package and achieve what you want.

Refer to the [Xamarin Forms Custom Renderers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for more details.

> Otherwise, try to create your project as a Shared project instead of .NET Standard project.
>
> Refer to the [Shared Project documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) for more details.